# Creating a GPO, batch file or VBS, to check if registry exists

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, registry, gpo

I'm creating a GPO to check if a registry value exists on 32 and 64 bit machines.  I rather only create one script, instead of two.  The script should check the value of a key, if it's a certain text, then exit, if not, delete the value.

I thought reg query would work, but that does not query the key.

KEY: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX`
OR KEY: `>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX`

`VALUE: 00 00 00 09 1A`

If that value exist, leave it, if not, delete it.

```
echo off

reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security<br>
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto not_64bit

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ /d "00 00 00 09 1A"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto end
Reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t 
goto end

:not_64bit
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ /d "00 00 00 09 1A"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto end
Reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Security /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /f

:end
```

Comment: Post what you've tried already.

Comment: Try: echo %ERRORLEVEL% to see what errorlevel the reg query is raising when it exits.

Comment: Yes but how can I get it to figure out if it's 32 bit, check one key, if its 64 bit check the other key?

Comment: Check for the Wow6432Node key first, if it returns nothing, check the normal key.

Comment: but in my logic I have, check the 64bit key, if the key value doesnt exists (which it wont in 32 bit) then add the key (but I dont want that).

Comment: And in some cases, my 64 bit machines have the key "directx" just no values inside, even better. i think i have to check if the key exists first, then run a sub command; else run the 32 bit command.

Comment: @echo off
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX
if errorlevel 1 goto not_64bit
Reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX /v InstalledVersion
goto end

:not_64bit
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX" /v InstalledVersion
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0000000900000000" goto end
Reg Delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX" /v InstalledVersion

:end

Comment: Check for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node

Comment: That works but i am getting an error with my "if "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0000000900000000" - the value equals what's in brackets but it still wants to delete the registry.

Comment: I think == is the string comparison operator, EQU would be for numeric functions, since you have all those zeros prefixing your number, they may be getting dropped.

Comment: I updated my code with what I am working with but am still getting errors querying a specific key, with a specific algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This may help - it's not tested.

```
@echo off

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" >nul 2>&1 || goto not_64bit
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ |find "00 00 00 09 1A" >nul
if errorlevel 1 Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /f
goto :EOF

:not_64bit
reg query  "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ |find "00 00 00 09 1A" >nul 2>&1 && goto :EOF
Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /f
```

Comment: That works but I need the opposite of ">nul 2>&1" in the 2nd last statement. Right now the "reg delete" only execute if it finds the value in the string.  I want it to execute if it doesn't find the value.

Comment: Replaced `||` with `&&` there to skip if the string is found.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick ...

```
@echo off

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" || goto not_64bit

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ |findstr -i /c:"065fac" || goto 64bitkey
goto :end

:64bitkey
Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ /d " " /f
goto :end

:not_64bit
reg query  "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ |findstr -i /c:"065fac" || goto 32bitkey
goto :end

:32bitkey
Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Security" /v AllowedRootCAHashCode /t REG_SZ /d " " /f

:end
```